# Oracle Change Backupset Command

Tags: oracle, rman

I am trying to enable a backupset. This backupset physically exists on disk along with other backupsets. I am issuing following command which results in a error:

```
RMAN> change backupset 4882 available;

using channel ORA_DISK_1    
using channel ORA_DISK_2    
using channel ORA_DISK_3    
using channel ORA_DISK_4

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================    
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============    
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================

RMAN-03002: failure of available command at 07/24/2020 14:37:16    
RMAN-06160: no backup pieces found for backup set key: 4882


RMAN> list backupset 4882;

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================

RMAN-03002: failure of list command at 07/24/2020 17:39:01
RMAN-06160: no backup pieces found for backup set key: 4882

RMAN>report obsolete;

Backup Set           4872   17-FEB-20
Backup Piece       4872   17-FEB-20          /oracle/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/cc/cc/90223CE92F61074BE0536A4E110AC491/backupset/2020_02_17/o1_mf_nnnd1_DAILY_IUB_h4l_.bkp

Backup Set           4898   22-JUL-20
Backup Piece       4898   22-JUL-20
          /oracle/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/cc/cc/backupset/2020_07_22/o1_mf_nnndf_TAG20200722T233833_hkjjt55t_.bkp

Backup Set           4899   22-JUL-20
  Backup Piece       4899   22-JUL-20          /oracle/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/cc/cc/backupset/2020_07_22/o1_mf_nnndf_TAG20200722T233833_hkjjtool_.bkp


RMAN> list backup summary
4881    B  A  A DISK        17-FEB-20       1       1       YES
     ARC_DAILY_IUB

4883    B  F  A DISK        21-FEB-20       1       1       NO        


RMAN> validate backupset 4882;

Starting validate at 24-JUL-20
using channel ORA_DISK_1
using channel ORA_DISK_2
using channel ORA_DISK_3
using channel ORA_DISK_4

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================

RMAN-03002: failure of validate command at 07/24/2020 17:50:56
RMAN-06160: no backup pieces found for backup set key: 4882
```

Also, RMAN is also not listing this backupset in LIST BACKUPSET SUMMARY command though it can list other backupsets which physically exists at the same disk location.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: RMAN Catalog is not available

Comment: Please perform the following command and report the result. (1)list backupset; (2)report obsolete; (3)crosscheck backupset; (4)validate backupset 4882.

Comment: Added details of all commands

Comment: This is good. Now please do one more time as mentioned.(1) list backupset; 2)crosscheck backupset;

Comment: After these two commands, list backupset 4882 is giving same error again.

Comment: crosscheck backupset;

Comment: You did crosscheck and rman can't find it means it wasn't there or renamed or deleted! Your effort should stop at here! Poor you!